# Missing Product scope after create websites/stores/storeviews via Data/Patch - Magento V2.4 Enterprise

Tags: magento2.4, patch-data

I faced an issue.
 After create script Data/Patch to create multi websites/stores/storeviews. At dropdown of Scope Product, i dont see new websites/stores/storeviews, in spite of it has in configuration tab. 
Please, show me my mistake.

This is my code :
[image]

---

When edit a product, we can see Product Scope section, it's on the top-left screen. After all, It only show "Default" value
[image]

Comment: Did you assign the product to the newly created websites?

Comment: @Marius, no, i dont talk about assign product to any websites.

Comment: I want to talk about Product Scope in Product page admin. 
This's a dropdown. It's on the top-left

Comment: It is somehow related. In the scope dropdown you only see the websites/ store views assigned to the product. Assign the product to a newly created website , save it and you should see the storeviews for that website in the dropdown.

Comment: oh my god :(  It's so bad!
I misunderstand about drop-down Product Scope. 

@Marius , Thanks you so much.